# Can I connect more than one sensors to a raspberry pi wirelessly

Tags: wireless, data-transfer

I am getting a raspberry pi for my birthday and decided to do a little research. While following a few tutorials I noticed that they all are using different raspberry pi machines for each project.

I was wondering if it's possible to use one raspberry pi as a main device to make "API" calls to other devices (preferable wirelessly) without having to buy a separate raspberry pi to communicate with.

I will give a simple example:
Lets say I have a plant watering system. And I want to fetch some data about my plant wirelessly. Is there an option to get it to communicate without buying an other raspberry pi?

Comment: Welcome and nice to meet you.  Ah, let me see. This might help you: ESP8266 WiFi Temperature and Humidity Sensor - EasyIoT 2015
https://www.instructables.com/id/ESP8266-WiFi-temperature-and-humidity-logger/. Have a great project. Cheers.

Comment: You can find references of wired and wireless smart garden sensors in the following forum discussion: (2) "RPI Zero W multiple sensors":
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=233311. You can find wireless sensors from Amazon and AliExpress, but they are 10 times more expensive than wired ones, and I think they are a bit hard to set up, compared to wired sensor. So I would suggest to first try wired sensors, then upgrade to wireless.

Comment: I do not understand the idea. To communicate with the RasPi you need another computer. It can be a RasPi but you can also use a laptop, desktop, smartphone or whatever you want.